# Prolog code not compiling anymore on linux

Tags: compiler-errors, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm doing a programming project in `Prolog (SWI-Prolog)` for my university, and after a month of working on it on a linux machine, the code is not compiling anymore, giving me errors of the kind `"Error: Operator Expected"` in random places.

The strange thing is that the very same code is perfectly compiling and working on windows, but I keep having those compiling errors on linux machines (not only mine, I tried also with other machines).

I thought it was an end of line error, so I tried changing the end of line on Sublime Text, than I tried converting to linux format using tools like `"dos2unix"` and many more I found on the internet, but the file is still not compiling.

Comment: check versions, starting swipl alone

Comment: @CapelliC is 7.3 on windows and 6.6 on linux, but the thing I can't explain is that it was compiling on linux before.

Comment: I found the error. Apparently with the version 6.6 you can't use no parameter functions, but you can do it in the 7.3, and I think that during those weeks I reinstalled swipl using the old version (not noticing it). That's why it was working before and not now. Thank you anyway